# Adding clob column to Oracle database using sqlloader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm having a file like this delimited by '|'

```
some varchar text | some varchar text | some varchar text | very long text >3500
```

I need to upload this file using sqlloader . 
the schema of the table is

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 TIME                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(60)
 EXCEPTION                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(300)
 DETAILS                                          CLOB
```

The content of the control file is

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
REPLACE
INTO TABLE BX_TWISTER_ERRORS
fields terminated by '|'
(
  NAME,
  TIME,
  EXCEPTION,
  DETAILS
)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Variable length field exceeds maximum length.

For each details field .

Can anyone give any suggestions or solutions for uploading this kinda delimited file using SQL loader?

Comment: See here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96652/ch07.htm#1006805

Answer (score 3):

Just add CHAR(10000) ore desired size in your control file.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
REPLACE
INTO TABLE BX_TWISTER_ERRORS
fields terminated by '|'
(
  NAME,
  TIME,
  EXCEPTION,
  DETAILS CHAR(10000)
)
```

Comment: FYI - sqlldr's internal char buffers are only 255.  If you are reading in data fields larger than that you will get the error.  I am in the habit of always creating the control file with a CHAR(X) that matches the table.  Actually I have a function that will generate a skeleton control file from a table that sets this up to remove some of the tedious work. I posted it before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37947714/2543416